# Efficient and non-interfering way of replacing multiple substrings in a String

Tags: java, string, replace

I'm trying to apply the same replacement instructions several thousand times to different input strings with as little overhead as possible. I need to consider two things for this:

1. The search Strings aren't necessarily all the same length: one may be just "a", another might be "ch", yet another might be "sch"
2. What was already replaced shall not be replaced again: If the replacement patterns are [a->e; e->a], "beat" should become "baet", not "baat" or "beet".

With that in mind, this is the code I came up with:

```
public class Replacements {
    private String[] search;
    private String[] replace;
    Replacements(String[] s, String[] r)
    {
        if (s.length!=r.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for (int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
        {
            map.put(s[i], r[i]);
        }
        List<String> sortedKeys = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
        Collections.sort(sortedKeys, new StringLengthComparator());
        this.search = sortedKeys.toArray(new String[0]);
        Stack<String> r2 = new Stack<>();
        sortedKeys.stream().forEach((i) -> {
            r2.push(map.get(i));
        });
        this.replace = r2.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
    public String replace(String input)
    {
        return replace(input,0);
    }
    private String replace(String input,int i)
    {
        String out = "";
        List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(input.split(this.search[i],-1));
        for (Iterator it = parts.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        {
            String part = it.next().toString();
            if (part.length()>0 && i<this.search.length-1) out += replace(part,i+1);
            if (it.hasNext()) out += this.replace[i];
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

And then

```
String[] words;
//fill variable words
String[] s_input = "ou|u|c|ch|ce|ci".split("\\|",-1);
String[] r_input = "u|a|k|c|se|si".split("\\|",-1);
Replacements reps = new Replacements(s_input,r_input);
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(reps.replace(word));
}
```

(`s_input` and `r_input` would be up to the user, so they're just examples, just like the program wouldn't actually use `println()`)

This code makes sure longer search strings get looked for first and also covers the second condition above.

It is, however, quite costly. What would be the most efficient way to accomplish what I'm doing here (especially if the number of Strings in `words` is significantly large)?

With my current code, "couch" should be converted into "kuc" (except it doesn't, apparently; it now does, thanks to the -1 in `split(p,-1)`)

Comment: You're going to have trouble with `split("|")` (the argument is a regex). You should use `split("\\|")` if you really must; but it would be better to construct your map explicitly, and pass that as a parameter to `Replacements`.

Comment: The `split("|")` part is only to illustrate what would be inside `s_input` and `r_input`. The actual code would derive those contents differently. But I'll edit the code here to eliminate that.

Comment: To be honest, if you want as little overhead as possible your ideal solution would be to iterate the char array (one time) and track history for anything replacement-wise that replaces more than one char. Aka ditching any regex.

Comment: You might want to look into using the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full solution but it shows how to scan the input and find all target substrings in one pass. You would use a `StringBuilder` to assemble the result, looking up the replacements in a Map as you are currently doing. Use the start and end indexes to handle copying of non-matching segments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(ou|ch|ce|ci|u|c)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("auouuchcceaecxici");
    while (m.find())
    {
        MatchResult r = m.toMatchResult();
        System.out.printf("s=%d e=%d '%s'\n", r.start(), r.end(), r.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
s=1 e=2 'u'
s=2 e=4 'ou'
s=4 e=5 'u'
s=5 e=7 'ch'
s=7 e=8 'c'
s=8 e=10 'ce'
s=12 e=13 'c'
s=15 e=17 'ci'
```

Note the strings in the regex have to be sorted in order of descending length to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One could make a regex pattern from the keys and leave it to that module for optimization.

Obviously

```
"(ou|u|ch|ce|ci|c)"
```

needs to take care of ce/ci/c, either by reverse sorting or immediately as tree:

```
"(c(e|h|i)?|ou|u)"
```

Then

```
String soughtKeys = "ou|u|ch|ce|ci|c"; // c last
String replacements = "u|a|c|se|si|k";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
... fill map

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(" + soughtKeys + ")");

for (String word : words) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(word);
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, map.get(m.group());
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", word, sb.toString());
}
```

The advantage being that regex is quite smart (though slow), and replacements are not done over replaced text.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Replacements
{
    private String[] search; // sorted in descending length and order, eg: sch, ch, c
    private String[] replace; // corresponding replacement

    Replacements(String[] s, String[] r)
    {
        if (s.length != r.length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        final TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(Collections.reverseOrder());

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
            map.put(s[i], r[i]);

        this.search = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
        this.replace = map.values().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
    }

    public String replace(String input)
    {
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        // start of yet-to-be-copied substring
        int s = 0;

        SEARCH:
        for (int i = s; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < this.search.length; p++)
            {
                if (input.regionMatches(i, this.search[p], 0, this.search[p].length()))
                {
                    // append buffer and replacement
                    result.append(input, s, i).append(this.replace[p]);

                    // skip beyond current match and reset buffer
                    i += this.search[p].length();
                    s = i--;

                    continue SEARCH;
                }
            }
        }

        if (s == 0) // no matches? no changes!
            return input;

        // append remaining buffer
        return result.append(input, s, input.length()).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `this.search` and `this.replace` end up being `[ou, u]` and `[si, k]` respectively if you feed `[ou, u, c, ch, ce, ci]` and `[u, a, k, c, se, si]` as `s` and `r` into your version of `Replacement(String[] s, String[] r)`

Comment: @joelproko ...probably because of a broken ```StringLengthComparator```, that sets Strings of equal length equal to one another in the TreeMap. Just leave that thing out and simply use ```Collections.reverseOrder()``` (without parameters) for a reverse natural ordering in the TreeMap. A simple reverse natural order of the search keys is totally fine to handle the ```[c, ch, ce, ci]``` cases, because longer words will naturally be reverse-ordered before their shorter prefixes. There's no need to explicitely check the search key length.

Comment: Your replace function is significantly better though. In a benchmark where I used the search/replace pairs in my example to go over all lowercase-letters-only entries in the British English hunspell dictionary (63230 words), it clocked in around ~23 miliseconds per run (through the entire wordlist), averaged over 10000 runs. The cobbled-together function I put in my example takes about 140 miliseconds per run for the exact same task (averaged over only 100 runs, didn't bother to go higher). (Both benchmarks without outputting or storing the output of the replace() function to anything)

Comment: I edited my post/code to remove the broken StringLengthComparator.

Comment: Given the output it gave before, are you sure the TreeMap maintains the key=>value link? Because it looks like it might sort keys and values independently (rather than sorting by key [length] only).

Also, in the example given, a reverse natural order would be fine for the [c, ch, ce, ci] part, but not for the [ou, u] part, unless I'm mistaken (otherwise, something like [te, e] would have the wrong order).